# GattServer conflcits with Microsoft Advertising Beacon on Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, hololens, bluetooth-gatt

i'm experiencing weird issue with HL2.
I'm working on BLE unity app and as such i've created gattserver that exposes a gatt service and some characteristics. Nothing fancy.
It was working just fine. I could connect to HL2 as central and write to characteristics. But then it stopped working.
Did some digging with nrfScanner and it turned out that HL2 advertises both my gatt services and "microsoft advertising beacon". never both at the same time. it's always this or that.
Right now writing to characteristic is possible only if i hit short window opportunity of 1-2 seconds.

I have no idea if this Beacon is the culprit or if it's been there all the time but the issue seems to appear out of nowehere and I haven't experianced it in the last 3 months of development :/.

See video

[Microsoft Advertising Beacon fighting with BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublishers from UWP sample app as seen in nrcConnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1aat.gif)

- My first thought was i've changed something in my code so i reverted to the code i knew was working. No luck.
- Beacon does not show up unless i start GattServer.
- Then i've rolled back to older windows on hololens2 (there was an update recentyl). No luck.
- It also happens when running this sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/win10-2004/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement (which doesn't use gattservice provider but BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher) so looks like it's not unity related.

So i've basically ran out of ideas here.

Comment: hello @trueillusion. what OS build is your HL running? we are currently investigating internally and trying to repro.

Comment: hi @ClaudiuC_MSFT, i've just noticed yout reply.

Comment: hi @ClaudiuC_MSFT, i've just noticed your reply.
i've tested with
20348.1531 and all releases down to  20348.1503 - all the same.
what's intrasting - during 3 months of development i haven't noticed this issue - peripherals could find and connect to holo without issues. so my first thought was "update happend"

Answer (score 3):

We tested both https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/win10-2004/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement and https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/win10-2004/Samples/BluetoothLE samples and can confirm that the behavior you noticed in nrfScanner (beacons alternating between different advertisements) is by design. Additionally, there were no issues with reading or writing to the Gatt Server characteristics.